I want change favicon.ico in nextjs
I want change favico.ico in nextjs but it dosn't change.
I tried these steps : {

downloaded an icon from favicon generated
replaced that icon with default icon inside app directory but dosen't work
imported icon and used icon value inside metadata object but dosent work
also deleted .next folder for reset cashe
I did every other ways inside internet (stackoverflow , youtube and ...) but dosent work
}


Browser's aggressively cache favicons. Have you tried fully clearing the browser cache?

Does this answer your question? How do I force a favicon refresh?

With the information you gave I'm unsure what exactly the problem is. But I can give some general advice.
Make sure your icon ends in .ico
For example favicon.png is not supported in Next.js.
Delete your .next folder and re-run the app
This is where Next.js caches files so deleted and re-runing your app might help
Force the browser to reset your favicon
Sometimes the problem is on the browser. Clear the cache in your browser.

thanks. with clear browser cashe it works
